Narrowing fails for assignments with: Type is not assignable to 'never'
I want to dynamically modify values in the object:
interface myType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
const formFields: (keyof myType)[] = ['id', 'name']
let test: myType= {
  id: 0,
  name: `name`
}
let data: string[] = ['1', 'Name']
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const field = formFields[i];
  if (typeof test[field] === 'number') {
    test[field] = Number(data[i]);
  } else if (typeof test[field] === 'string') {
    test[field] = data[i];
  }
}

but I can't avoid this error:
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)

Although it doesn't affect the actual operation.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to change the name of your interface from type to something more conventional, like maybe MyType. Interface names are generally in UpperCamelCase and type is a TS keyword which, while not prohibited from being a type name, is going to confuse people.

(please see previous comment) Unfortunately TS cannot follow the logic of test[field] === 'number' as a way of guarding test[field], especially for writing. If you want to help TS see this, you probably should refactor that check into a custom type guard function, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you, it did solve the issue, there are no more errors, but I don't understand why in the second paragraph it can still write "} else if (typeof test[field] === 'string') {", and there is no error, because in my actual project there are many different types, not just number and string.

In the example there's only number and string so TS knows that. If you put more things then you need to call more type guard functions. I can abstract these multiple functions into a single one such as shown in this playground link. Should I write that up as an answer?

@jcalz But this doesn’t give an error. Is it because this is a custom type?

It's because Partial<Record<Status, boolean>> is a weak type with all optional props, so {} is assignable to it, and string is assignable to {}, as shown here.  I'd explain further but you've already accepted the other answer (and I'm not sure that the possibility of differing getter/setter type is relevant to your question) so I'm not inclined to do much more here, unless you want to see me write an answer.

In JS/TS properties may have getters and setters and their types may differ. You check type of what the getter returns, but setter may accept a different type. Look at this example:
const obj = {
  val: "",
  get prop(): string {
    return this.val;
  },
  set prop(val: number) {
    this.val = val.toString()
  },
}

// The following assignment does not compile:
if (typeof obj.prop === "string") { // here prop looks like a string property
  obj.prop = "str" // but here prop is already a number property
}

This example should clarify why TS behaves like that.
Q: But why the type of the property is inferred as never?
A: Compiler has some knowledge about the type of getter, but nothing about the setter. Thus, it can't guarantee type-safe assignments. The never type is the one you can never assign to. It prevents you from making unsafe assignments, but you can bypass it (see bellow).

Bellow are two options for you to solve the issue.
The first option keeps your logic and just bypasses the TS error:
(in fact, it's not type safe and may be misused)
interface type {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
const formFields: (keyof type)[] = ['id', 'name']
let test: type = {
  id: 0,
  name: `name`
}
let data: string[] = ['1', 'Name']
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const field = formFields[i];
  if (typeof test[field] === 'number') {
    setTestField(field, Number(data[i]))
  } else if (typeof test[field] === 'string') {
    setTestField(field, data[i])
  }
}
function setTestField<T extends keyof type>(key: T, value: type[T]): void {
  test[key] = value
}

Or a shorter variation of this option is provided here by @jcalz.
And the second option is a slight rewrite of your logic:
interface type {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
const formFields: (keyof type)[] = ['id', 'name']
let test: type = {
  id: 0,
  name: `name`
}
let data: string[] = ['1', 'Name']
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const field = formFields[i];
  switch (field) {
    case 'id':
      test.id = Number(data[i]);
      break;
    case 'name':
      test.name = data[i]
      break;
  }
}

Maybe one of them will work for your case.

Your first option is unfortunately a fancy way of effectively doing a type assertion; nothing stops you from getting it wrong. TS isn't fully type safe, so this isn't your fault or anything, but it's giving a misleading sense of safety. You might as well just write this for all it's helping.

@jcalz yes, completely agree regarding the first option. That's what I meant saying it just bypasses the TS error. But your clarification is helpful! Thanks for your second example. I wasn't aware we can use as on the left side of an assignment. Let me update the answer to reflect that.

Thank you. So, the reason for this issue is because the getter type and setter type of 'test[field]' are inconsistent, right? But why would the accepted type be "never"? I've only set it to number and string.

@ZVMAGL3 compiler has some knowledge about the type of getter, but nothing about the setter. Thus, it can't guarantee type-safe assignments. The never type is the one you can't assign to. It prevents you from making unsafe assignments, but if you want, you can bypass it.
